# Trying to use the Yajl example code, don't know how to give the input to the program

Tags: c, json, yajl

I've compiled the code provided by YAJL library in C. Don't know why the compiled program not parsing my file or is my file format is wrong?

I'm quite new in parsing JSON file.

This is where C code example located at https://lloyd.github.io/yajl/
Don't know do I need to paste the entire code or link is fine?

**Myfile.**

```
cat input_file.json 
helllooooooooooo
```

When I ran the program `./a.out json_reformat input_file.json`, it doesn't do anything. `./a.out -m json_reformat input_file.json` this also didnt work.

I tried with -u and -m option nothing worked.

It print out the usage in STDOUT like this.

```
usage:  json_reformat [options]
    -m minimize json rather than beautify (default)
    -u allow invalid UTF8 inside strings during parsing
```

Comment: You appear to be asking about the use of some software, rather than a coding question. Such is off-topic here and the question is likely to get closed. Maybe try SuperUser or perhaps the support options listed on the YAJL page (e.g. IRC, mailing list, github, etc)

Comment: Alright, Well if it is not the right forum then I will move my question to SuperUser.